# How to create Woocommerce Custom Currency Symbol using Wordpress Plugin "Code Snippets"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am wanting to change Woocommerce to display a volume unit of measure instead of currency.
It appears that one way of doing it is to modify a child theme functions.php file. However, i have been advised against that in favour of using a Wordpress plugin called Code Snippets.

I am not sure how to do this correctly. I have included some code below. Essentially i just want to create a custom currency to show m<sup>3</sup> that i can select as the default currency in Woocommerce.

Some may wonder what on earth this is needed for...I am creating a volume calculator for a removalist company using Woocommerce. It is not for payment gateway use!

Woocommerce is running on Wordpress with Code Snippets plugin.

Here is the code i have thus far...

```
/**
 * Custom currency and currency symbol
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currencies', 'add_my_currency' );

function add_my_currency( $currencies ) {
     $currencies['ABC'] = __( 'Currency name', 'woocommerce' );
     return $currencies;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'add_my_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function add_my_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
     switch( $currency ) {
          case 'ABC': $currency_symbol = 'm[sup]3[/sup]'; break;
     }
     return $currency_symbol;
}
```

Comment: My I know what does it returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using Following Code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currencies', 'add_my_currency',20,1 );

function add_my_currency( $currencies ) { 

    $currencies['ABC'] = __( 'Currency name', 'woocommerce' ); 
    return $currencies;

}

add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'add_my_currency_symbol', 20, 2);


function add_my_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
    switch( $currency ) {
      case 'ABC': $currency_symbol = ' m&sup3;  '; 
      break; 
    } 

    return $currency_symbol; 
}
```

Comment: woohoo..you genius. Thank you so much for this. One final question...currently in the woomcommerce currency selector, this currency displays as currency name(<sup>3</<sup>). How do i change this to say "Volume"?I assume that i just change $currencies['ABC'] = __( 'Currency name', 'woocommerce' ); so that Currency name reads Volume but i also want to include m3 (with the "3" as superscript

Comment: excellent thanks very much. Works a charm. May i ask why it is that <sup>3</sup> doesnt work whereas m&sup3 does?

Comment: &sup is html predefined character that's why its rendered easily, <sup> </sup>  is  a html tag , when it comes to render the html into html sometimes it does not work. in the select list of currencies we were rendering the html tag inside the options tag so it should have worked but after then the select list have applied the select2 js it converts the html into text between the option tags thats why <sup>3</sup> didn't work there..and &sup worked...

Comment: also the default select list does not allow to add html its get filtered automatically and show nothing only text is allowed in select lists

Answer (score 0):

Better try chaging the following line:

```
case 'ABC': $currency_symbol = ' m &sup3;  ';
```

to

```
case 'ABC': $currency_symbol = ' & #13221;  ';
```

Because HTML encoding erases space after `&`